# Sprout forms entries saving on staging but not live environment

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

We have a sprout form at staging.efficiencyforaccess.org/concept-note that successfully submits and saves data to Craft, but when pushed to the live environment (efficiencyforaccess.org/concept-note) the form data will submit but not save, and often causes the site to timeout.

The code is exactly the same on both environments, so why would the live version not work if the staging version does?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Save Data setting in the Form plugin settings and the Individual Form settings is enabled?

Comment: Also, make sure that you don't have the cache tag wrapped around the form. Sometimes that is only enabled in the live environment.